# Excel sorting is stuck when ClosedXML is used

Tags: closedxml, columnsorting

I have a xlsx of 14000 rows.
I can sort it by a column in a second using the standard Excel app.
When I try to do the same in `ClosedXML`, it is stuck. I mean that it is extremely slow (like 10 minutes or even more), but eventually it completes the operation.
So let's say I create a file

```
XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook();
IXLWorksheet ws = wb.AddWorksheet("my test");
ws.Cell(1, 1).Value = "A";
ws.Cell(1, 2).Value = "B";
for (int i = 0; i < 14000; i++)
{
    ws.Cell(i + 2, 1).Value = i;
    ws.Cell(i + 2, 2).Value = i % 2;
}
wb.SaveAs("test.xlsx");
```

Now there are several ways to sort it by the column B, for example

```
var tab = ws.Range(1,1,14001,2);
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
Console.WriteLine("start");
stopwatch.Start();
tab.SetAutoFilter();
wb.SaveAs("test.xlsx");
ws.AutoFilter.Sort(2);
stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Sorted after " + (int)stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + " seconds");
wb.SaveAs("test.xlsx");
```

Should I switch to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` to sort a table by a column? Or is there a usable method in `ClosedXML`?

Comment: Sorting performance is greatly improved in this ClosedXML pull request: https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/pull/1649

Comment: @FracoisBotha Thank you!! I'll try it out soon!) Btw you could also share it as a proper answer here, I'd be happy to accept it eventually.

Comment: The PR is still work in progress and there are some issues to iron out. Once it's merged, if ever, I'll put it down as an answer too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, sure, the Interop is much better for sorting, it is immediate in this case while ClosedXML is not usable.
Here is the sample code

```
 var excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
 // Make the object visible.
 excelApp.Visible = true;
 excelApp.Workbooks.Open(Path.Combine( Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "test.xlsx"));
 Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)excelApp.ActiveSheet;
```

Make sure to use ClosedXML before the above to create the spreadsheet (it is faster than interop *in that case*).

Finally the sorting part

```
var tab = (Range)ws.Range[ws.Cells[2, 1], ws.Cells[14001, 2]];
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
Console.WriteLine("start");
stopwatch.Start();
ws.Cells[1, 2].AutoFilter();
tab.Select();
tab.Sort(ws.Cells[2,2], XlSortOrder.xlAscending);
Console.WriteLine("Sorted after " + (int)stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + " seconds");    
excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Save();
excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close();
excelApp.Quit();
```

It will take a second, as it is supposed to.

Sorting helper library [shared](https://github.com/giuliohome/SortXlsxLib/blob/main/ExcelInterop.cs)